# Rotation by $\phi$ of the axes which makes the pair of straight lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ independent of $xy$ in the rotated coordinate axes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I am supposed to find angle $\phi$ by which the coordinate axes must be rotated so that the equation of the pair of straight lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ becomes independent of $xy$ term in the rotated coordinate axes.

---

**My Attempt**

$$a(x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi)^2+2h(x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi)(y\cos\phi-x\sin\phi)+b(y\cos\phi-x\sin\phi)^2\\ xy \text{ term}\rightarrow (a-b)\sin(2\phi)+2h\cos(2\phi)=0$$

$$\phi=\dfrac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\dfrac{2h}{b-a}\right)$$

---

In my book the answer is given to be $1/2\arctan(2h/(a-b))$. My take on this is that since rotation can be both clockwise or anticlockwise, both the books' answer and the answer I arrived at are correct. Is that so?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Comment: +1 for your attempt. You shouldn't have deleted your last question. Will upvote it if you repost it.

Comment: @Isham Thanks. Would you also kindly demonstrate the procedure for solving the ODE?

Comment: If you want to learn ODE it's better to start with DE with known coefficients. The one you posted has $m,b,k$ as coefficents so you have to discuss the solution depending on certain values of these parameters.